# Get function name when ContextDecorator is used as a decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have the following context manager and decorator to time any given function or code block:

```
import time
from contextlib import ContextDecorator


class timer(ContextDecorator):
    def __init__(self, label: str):
        self.label = label

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start_time = time.perf_counter()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        net_time = time.perf_counter() - self.start_time
        print(f"{self.label} took {net_time:.1f} seconds")
        return False
```

You can use it as a context manager:

```
with timer("my code block"):
    time.sleep(2)

# my code block took 2.0 seconds
```

You can also use it as a decorator:

```
@timer("my_func")
def my_func():
    time.sleep(3)

my_func()

# my_func took 3.0 seconds
```

The only thing I don't like is having to manually pass the function name as the `label` when it's used as a decorator. I would love for the decorator to automatically use the function name if no label is passed:

```
@timer()
def my_func():
    time.sleep(3)

my_func()

# my_func took 3.0 seconds
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you also override the `__call__()` method inherited from the `ContextDecorator` [base class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/contextlib.py#L60) in your `timer` class, and add a unique default value to the initializer for the `label` argument, you can check for that and grab the function's `__name__` when it's called:

```
import time
from contextlib import ContextDecorator


class timer(ContextDecorator):
    def __init__(self, label: str=None):
        self.label = label

    def __call__(self, func):
        if self.label is None:  # Label was not provided
            self.label = func.__name__  # Use function's name.
        return super().__call__(func)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start_time = time.perf_counter()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        net_time = time.perf_counter() - self.start_time
        print(f"{self.label} took {net_time:.1f} seconds")
        return False


@timer()
def my_func():
    time.sleep(3)

my_func()  # -> my_func took 3.0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on an examination of `ContextDecorator`'s [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/contextlib.py#L60), there does not seem to be any way the name of the wrapped function can be made available to the contextmanager. Instead, you can create your own version of `ContextDecorator`, overriding `__call__`

```
import time
import functools, contextlib
class _ContextDecorator(contextlib.ContextDecorator):
   def __call__(self, func):
      self.f_name = func.__name__
      @functools.wraps(func)
      def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
          with self._recreate_cm():
             return func(*args, **kwargs)
      return wrapper
```

Usage:

```
class timer(_ContextDecorator):
   def __init__(self, label: str = None):
      self.f_name = label
   def __enter__(self):
      self.start_time = time.perf_counter()
      return self
   def __exit__(self, *exc):
      net_time = time.perf_counter() - self.start_time
      print(f"{self.f_name} took {net_time:.1f} seconds")
      return False

with timer('my_func'):
   time.sleep(2)

@timer()
def my_func():
   time.sleep(3)

my_func()
```

Comment: You don't need to separately define your own version of `ContextDecorator` to override the `__call__()` method. Just do it in the subclass already being defined (as I've done in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70059951/355230)).

Comment: @martineau I think it makes more sense to keep the components separate. This type of behavior is expected to be provided by `ContextDecorator`, not `timer`. In fact, if such customizability is needed in the first place, then it should probably be implemented in its entirety in `timer`, not `ContextDecorator`.

Comment: I disagree about keeping them separate because I see little need for what `_ContextDecorator` is doing making its reuse unlikely in some other situation. Combining them into one class encapsulates what's going on better.